# Styles not display correctly in iOS phone gap app

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, cordova

Has next issues: in phone gap app styles shifting when launch app on iOS 6.1 
All styles was applied for correct rendering in browser(Safari, Chrome, Phone gap app ios7.1) but in  6.1 and less some elements shifts.
I use meta:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

Next problem is long list scrolling:
I append a couple of block like list and during scrolling on iOS 7.1 this list start twitches and freeze for a time but in iOS 6.1 and less(try on 5.1) this process work normal
So in my iPhone(7.1) in browser with long page has same problem also.
may be its known issue. 
Like plan B for first issue possible rewrite css after checking of a version but for second problem what i can to do?
Oh, i'm also try `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` for block with this list but it also don't help me .

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you are using inline styles, instead, use a stylesheet, as many inline styles are deprecated.  In css, most of the styling look the same, but with : instead of = , and there is no need for "" around each style.

Comment: can u tell me meta of locking inline styles(if it exist)?
or method for refresh(block it)

Comment: do you wish me to write the css? I could try, but many of the styling's you have used don't exist

Comment: also, using width=device-width only works when a device like a mobile is in portrait mode, if you turn it to landscape mode, the page will render with the width of portrait mode and only fill part of the screen

Comment: no)
may be i don't understand u exactly)
i have my own style sheet but for different os it render different styles)

Comment: I can't see any solution besides writing the styles you have used into your css doc then

Comment: So i'm rewrite this part for elder version
but what about scrolling?do you have such kind of problem?

Comment: sorry, can't help you there, I don't have this problem